# Python http proxy library based on libevent or comparable technology?

Tags: python, http, proxy, libevent

I'm looking to build an intelligent reverse http proxy capable of routing, header examination and enrichment (eg. examine and build cookies and http headers), and various other fanciness. For a general idea of what I'm looking to build see [Ruby Proxies for Scale and Monitoring](http://www.igvita.com/2009/04/20/ruby-proxies-for-scale-and-monitoring/)  - except in Python.

I realize that Twisted is an exceedingly good answer for this, and that eventmachine was inspired by Twisted, but I'm looking for something other than Twisted.

Ideally a library or package that includes http proxying capabilities I could modify with my own little plugins.

I remember seeing something based on eventlib that had http server capabilities built in, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm also taking a deep look at perlbal; that looks almost like the perfect solution, except it's in Perl.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Why exactly are you looking for something other than Twisted, which as you mention is a great answer AND "you can modify with your own little plugins" at will?

Comment: I've tried to like Twisted on multiple occasions, and while I like the concepts very much I've never actually enjoyed using it. I'm sure it's a shortcoming on my part and nothing to do with Twisted, but I'd like to try something different for a change.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if meets all your needs, but [proxylet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/proxylet/) is a reverse proxy based on Linden Lab's [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/).